# Can you use a custom Fragmenter with Elasticsearch highlighting?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, highlight

We have some documents that contain specially formatted information that we want to use when determining snippets. Lucene supports custom [Fragmenters](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_0_1/highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/Fragmenter.html), but I don't see support for that in the Elasticsearch API. Is there a way to override the snippet selection beyond what is listed in the API?

It looks like it is possible [with a plug-in](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/highlighting.html), is that the only way to achieve this?